# Cannot delete or update a parent row in bi-directionnelle relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have three tables :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DB`.`global_history` (
  `ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_HISTORY` INT(11) NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),

  CONSTRAINT `FK_HISTORY_GLOBAL_HISTORY`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_HISTORY`)
    REFERENCES `DB`.`history` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Second table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DB`.`history` (
  `ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TIMESTAMP` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));*
```

third table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DB`.`audit` (
  `ID` INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_HISTORY` INT(11) NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),

  CONSTRAINT `FK_HISTORY_AUDIT`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID_HISTORY`)
    REFERENCES `DB`.`history` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

**And these are my model classes :**

***Global history :***

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_HISTORY", nullable = true)
private History history;
```

***History :***

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "history", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
private List<GloabalHistory> globalHistories;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_AUDIT", nullable = true)
private Audit audit;
```

***Audit:***

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "audit", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
private List<History> histories;
```

but when I try to update a row in History (Second table) I get this error :

> --> Cannot delete or update a parent row : a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: It would help if you post the code used to update.

Comment: actually, it's simple i'm using this line `entityManager.merge(history)`

Comment: Have you modified the `ID` field?

Comment: no I didn't modify that

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` at all one to many relation,  and use `@Transactional` annotation at service class and use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` on save method. and also enable the transaction on the hibernate or Spring configuration.